# How to open firewall to access azure file storage

Tags: firewall, azure, server-message-block

We are going to use robocopy to keep a stack of encrypted files synced to an azure file share.

But what do we need to open on the firewall to let the backup server get to an azure storage file share? (This will be an SMB3 connection from Win2012-R2 to azure storage)

a) Open port 445

b) But what IP addresses?

Our storage account says regions: East US, West US

I found this page:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41653

which gives a LARGE list of ranges (50-100) to cover those two regions.

Must I add all those ranges to our firewall, or is there a more targeted way to discover the ip ranges to access:

.file.core.windows.net

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only workable path is to enable firewall to work with domains, and to then open it to:

my-sharename.file.core.windows.net

(For the appro share name / storage entity)

Comment: Up voting since I like this idea as a solution, but beware, Azure Storage does not yet support HTTPS with custom domains, which makes it useless. See the comments on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/ for more opinion...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no other way today than opening your firewall with these ranges of IP address (you found the right document).

If you want to restrict more communications you can do a double copy : 
1- From your datacenter to an Azure VM (you will open only the VM IP address  on your datacenter firewall) in the same region than the storage account.
2-  From your Azure VM to Azure File

Of course it's just a workaround (that add additional tasks) to have few IP / port opened between your datacenter to Azure File.

It would be a good idea to suggest an improvement on this point in Azure Storage uservoice ;-) https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage

Regards

Stanislas